# Serialization of nested classes using Jackson

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, objectmapper

Following is my class structure :

```
public interface AInf {
    public String getUniqueKey();
    // other getters
}

public interface BInf {
    public String getUniqueKey();
    // other getters
}

public interface CInf {
    public String getUniqueKey();
    // other getters
}

class A implements AInf {
    private String name;
    private String uniqueKey;
    private CInf c;
    // with getters and setters
    // also there are more fields with nested class structure
}

class B implements BInf {
    private String name;
    private String uniqueKey;
    private AInf a;
    private CInf c;
    // with getters and setters
    // also there are more fields with nested class structure
}

class C implements CInf {
    private String name;
    private String uniqueKey;
    private String value;
    // with getters and setters
}
```

While creating JSON using Jackson's ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString() it is creating whole JSON again for inner nested classes. Like :

```
A :- 
{
 "name" : "abc",
 "c" : {
 // whole C class JSON without unique Key
}
}

B :- 
{
"name" : "xyz",
"a" : {
 // whole A class JSON without unique Key
}
 "c" : {
 // whole C class JSON without unique Key
}
}

C :- 
{
"name" : "xyz",
"value" : "pqr"
}
```

**Is there any way to avoid re-creation of JSON for nested classes?**

Some statistics, I have total 600+ objects of type A, B and C combined. The JSON created using above method is of size 35 MB and it took more than 20+ mins.

Comment: try @JsonIgnore for feilds to skip

Comment: @VinodBokare yes. Used it where ever possible.

Comment: Do you want to avoid repeated serialisation of instances that have already been written, or do you want to ignore the fields?

Comment: @teppic I want to avoid repeated serialization of instances that have already been written. Ignoring fields is already achieved using @ JsonIgnore

Comment: Do your objects have unique keys? Annotate them with `@JsonIdentityInfo` if they do. This will let jackson collapse the objects to back-references.

Comment: @teppic Yes. I have uniqueKey. By using JsonIdentityInfo I am not able to collapse the objects with their references. May be because inside object wont produce the unique Key in the JSON.

Comment: @teppic tried with JsonIdentityInfo . Did not work.

Comment: You'll have to provide the code that "Did not work" if you want a fix. `JsonIdentityInfo` does what you want if set up correctly.

Comment: For your example code, you would need the following annotation on `A`, `B`, and `C`: `@JsonIdentityInfo(property = "uniqueKey", generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class)`